# Unable to use composer package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

I am trying to use the following class in a laravel 5 project. https://packagist.org/packages/mk-j/php_xlsxwriter#dev-master

I do the:

```
composer require mk-j/php_xlsxwriter
```

Then it gets downloaded in my vendor folder. However I am unable to use it in a controller as it cannot find the class XLSXWriter.

I then look at the composer.json of mk-j/php_xlsxwriter and see the following:

```
{
    "name": "mk-j/php_xlsxwriter",
    "description": "PHP Library to write XLSX files",
    "keywords": ["php", "library","xls", "xlsx", "excel"],
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter",
    "license": "MIT",

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["xlsxwriter.class.php"]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*"
    }
}
```

It looks like the class is not PSR-4 compliant. Should I tweak the composer.json here to try to make it compliant but then that does not see adequate as another developer would have to do the same.

What can I do to be able to use the class in a controller? I am not very PSR savvy.

Thank You

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to use the class. May be you need to register it in the `providers` and `aliases` arrays

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` have you tried?